# Is it possible to run different tasks on different schedules with prefect?

Tags: prefect

I'm moving my first steps with prefect, and I'm trying to see what its degrees of freedom are. To this end, I'm investigating whether prefect supports running different tasks *on different schedules* in the same python process. For example, Task A might have to run every 5 minutes, while Task B might run twice a day with a Cron scheduler.

It seems to me that schedules are associated with a *Flow*, not with a task, so to do the above, one would have to create two distinct one-task *Flows*, each with its own schedule. But even as that, given that running a flow is a blocking operation, I can't see how to "start" both flows concurrently (or pseudo-concurrently, I'm perfectly aware the flows won't execute on separate threads).

Is there a built-in way of getting the tasks running on their independent schedules? I'm under the impression that there *is* a way to achieve this, but given my limited experience with prefect, I'm completely missing it.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that schedules are associated with Flows and not Tasks, so the only place to add a schedule is a Flow. Running a Flow is a blocking operation if you are using the open source Prefect core only. For production use cases, it's recommended running your Flows against Prefect Cloud or Prefect Server. Cloud is the managed offering and Server is when you host it yourself. Note that Cloud has a very generous free tier.

When using a backend, you will use an agent that will kick off the flow run in a new process. This will not be blocking.

To start with using a backend, you can check the [docs here](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/getting-started/quick-start.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This Prefect Discourse topic](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-to-schedule-and-orchestrate-a-flow-of-flows-for-a-data-warehousing-etl-use-case/691) discusses a very similar problem and shows how you could solve it using a flow-of-flows orchestrator pattern.

One way to approach it is to leverage Caching to avoid recomputation of certain tasks that require lower-frequency scheduling than the main flow.

Comment: Thanks Anna - I have read indeed about the flow-of-flows pattern, but I was under the impression that the pattern is about modeling dependencies between flows. How would that pattern help me when I want to run independent tasks with different schedules?

Comment: Actually, are you suggesting that I create two one-task flows - say, Flow A containing only Task A, and Flow B containing only Task B - each with its own schedule, and then run the flows concurrently via a "parent flow" that comprises two StartFlowRun tasks?

Comment: There are so many ways you could solve it in Prefect! :) one would be to have normal tasks and leverage caching to avoid rerunning certain tasks - e.g., if you have an hourly flow and some tasks need to run only once per day, you can cache this task for 24 hours so that this task runs only once per day even though it's running as part of an hourly flow - here is an example syntax: 

```@task(cache_for=timedelta(hours=24))```